# initializing AWS with Springboot

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am trying to initialize and build a `Springboot` Application that uses `AWS` dependencies on Net Beans, however, I am having a problem building the project. After resolving the errors after creating the project I am getting an error when I try to build. The message I get is

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.support.io.ResourceLoaderBeanPostProcessor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'amazonS3' while setting constructor argument;`

I found some previous answers saying to put `cloud.aws.stack.auto=false` in my application.properties file, however, I seem to be getting the same problem after I clean and build again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building/ testing or running locally (as opposed to EC2) then you need to have a region property such as in `application.properties` assuming you use the default profile for build and test.

`cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-1`